# Rotating two objects

Tags: matrices, trigonometry, rotations

I have two lines. Both created in this format:
Line 1
$$line1 = \left\{ \begin{array}{c} startX, startY \\ endX, endY \end{array} \right\}$$
$$line2 = \left\{ \begin{array}{c} startX, startY \\ endX, endY \end{array} \right\}$$

For example:
$$line1 = \left\{ \begin{array}{c} 0, 0 \\ 50, 50 \end{array} \right\}$$
$$line2 = \left\{ \begin{array}{c} 0, 0 \\ 75, 75 \end{array} \right\}$$

I want to rotate them, but rotate them so that line2 will be to able have its center of rotation at points `endX`,`endY` of line1.
ie:
[image]

Then:
[image]
And then:
[image]

Both lines have a matrix of modelview.
I made up the following(**STARTING**):
$$vecSize = \left\{ \begin{array}{c} line1.endX - line1.startX;line1.endY - line1.startY; \end{array} \right\} $$
$$matLine1 = matLine1 * mat4(translate(100, 100, 0))$$
$$matLine2 = matLine2 * mat4(translate(100, 100, 0)) * mat4(translate(vecSize.X, vecSize.Y, 0))$$

And I got the following:
[image]
If I do this:
$$matLine1 = matLine1 * mat4(rotate(90, vec2d(0, 0, 1))$$
$$matLine2 = matLine2 * mat4(translate(-vecSize.X, -vecSize.Y, 0))$$
$$matLine2 = matLine2 * mat4(rotate(90, vec2d(0, 0, 1))$$
$$matLine2 = matLine2 * mat4(translate(vecSize.X, vecSize.Y, 0))$$
Very good. I see this:
[image]
If I do this(after **STARTING**):
$$matLine2 = matLine2 * mat4(rotate(20, vec2d(0, 0, 1))$$
$$matLine1 = matLine1 * mat4(rotate(90, vec2d(0, 0, 1))$$
$$matLine2 = matLine2 * mat4(translate(-vecSize.X, -vecSize.Y, 0))$$
$$matLine2 = matLine1 * mat4(rotate(90, vec2d(0, 0, 1))$$
$$matLine2 = matLine2 * mat4(translate(vecSize.X, vecSize.Y, 0))$$
I see this:
[image]
I want all rotation and translation for `line2` to be relative to `line1`. `Line2` should rotate about {`Line1.endX`, `Line1.endY`};